# SignalR When calling connection.StartAsync() from Blazor WASM client Error 500 Patterns.RoutePatternException

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr, blazor-webassembly

I am getting Error 5000 on server side with Patterns.RoutePatternException and message:

> *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternException: There is an incomplete parameter in the route template. Check that each '{'
> character has a matching '}' character.*

I am getting the follow exception on the serverside;

> 09/15/2020 21:06:17 -05:00 Error An unhandled exception has occurred
> while executing the request.
> **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternException: There is an incomplete parameter in the route template. Check that each '{'
> character has a matching '}' character.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternParser.Parse(String
> pattern)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternFactory.Parse(String
> pattern)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointFactory.AddEndpoints(List`1 endpoints, HashSet`1 routeNames, ActionDescriptor action,
> IReadOnlyList`1 routes, IReadOnlyList`1 conventions, Boolean
> createInertEndpoints)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource.CreateEndpoints(IReadOnlyList`1 actions, IReadOnlyList`1 conventions)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.UpdateEndpoints()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Initialize()**

This is my second app with Blazor/Core ASP 3.1 and I tried to copy the first working one. On the client side the code gets to StartAsync()

```
  Log.Warning("top of start service");
  connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .WithUrl(url)
      .Build();

  Log.Warning("after connect in start service");
  connection.Closed += async (error) =>
  {
    await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
    await connection.StartAsync();
  };
  connection.Reconnecting += error =>
  {
    Log.Error("Connection Lost attempting to reconnect: {@error}", error);

    // Notify users the connection was lost and the client is reconnecting.
    // Start queuing or dropping messages.

    return Task.CompletedTask;
  };
  try
  {
    Log.Warning("before start async");
    await connection.StartAsync();
    Log.Warning("after start async");
```

Program.cs

```
  var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
      .Build();

  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
      .CreateLogger();

  try
  {

    CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args)
      .WithParsed(RunOptions)
      .WithNotParsed(HandleParseError);

    BuildWebHost(args).Build().Run();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
}

public static IHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>

    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
          webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
          _ = webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:8080");
        }).UseSerilog();
```

Startup.cs

```
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
      {
        builder
        //.WithOrigins("http://localhost:44322")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyOrigin();
      }));

      services.AddSignalR();

      services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error");
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }
      else
      {
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error");
        //app.UseHsts();
      }
      app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
      app.UseDefaultFiles();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseRouting();


      //var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();


      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapHub<ShowsHub.BlazingShowsHub>("/shows");

        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
      });

    }
```

Suggestions?

Comment: There must be something wrong with your route template. Please check your route template like `[Route("api/users/{userId/login")]` missing `}`.

Comment: This should have been an answer so I could have upvoted it and marked it as solved.  never crossed my mind that it was in a controller, because I wasn't using controllers.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternException: There is
> an incomplete parameter in the route template. Check that each '{'
> character has a matching '}' character.

From the `RoutePatternException` you post, we can see it must be something wrong with the route template of controller. Please check your route template like `[Route("api/users/{userId/login")]` missing `}`.